# Coding an exercise and can't get it to work?

Tags: java, algorithm

This is in chapter 3 of the book we're using for my class, so they haven't introduced much. I've been at this for about 2 hours now and haven't gotten very far unfortunately. This is the problem:

Write a class "Bug" that models a bug moving along a horizontal line. The bug moves either to the right or left. Initially, the bug moves to the right, but it can turn to change its direction. In each move, its position changes by one unit in the current direction. Provide a constructor:

Public Bug(int initialPosition)

and methods:

turn, move, getPosition

this is a sample of how it should work in a tester class

```
bug bug1 = new bug(10)
bug1.move // now the position is 11
bug1.turn // changes direction
bug1.move // now the position is 10
```

this is all I have so far.

```
public class Bug {
private int initialPosition;
private int currentPosition;

public Bug(int initialPosition){
    this.initialPosition = initialPosition + 1;
}
public void turn(){

}
public void move(){
    currentPosition = initialPosition++;

}
public int getPosition(){
    return currentPosition;
}  
}
```

and my tester class

```
public class BugTester {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Bug roach = new Bug(10);
    roach.move();
    roach.move();
    System.out.println(roach.getPosition());
}

}
```

output:12

Comment: How does the output differ from your expectations?

Comment: Why do you think you need a field for the initial position? Why do you think that moving should unconditionally increment the position? Why do you think you don't need to remember the current direction in a field?

Comment: You're going to need a field in your `Bug` class that indicates which way the bug is facing, so the program knows whether to increase or decrease the position when the bug moves.

Comment: Expanding on what Sotirios said, it's also a good idea to make the title equally descriptive of the problem. That way, if you ever run into a similar problem *again*, you can find this relatively easily by reading question titles, rather than having to skim each individual question to see what the problem being addressed is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Bug {
private int position;
private int diff = 1;

public Bug(int position){
    this.position = position;
}
public void turn(){
    if(diff == 1){
       diff = -1;
    } else {
       diff = 1;
    }
}
public void move(){
    position += diff;

}
public int getPosition(){
    return position;
}  
}
```

Spend some time learning.

Comment: `public void turn() { diff = -diff; }` :-)